# Docker compose start without detach

Tags: docker, docker-compose

From terminal 1 there are multiple docker compose services running, from time to time I need to run another container (for testing purposes) from terminal 2. I should see the output of the testing container from terminal 2, but this is not possible when using the `start` command because the output will be detached.

Basically I need the same behaviour as the `run` command without creating more containers but the `start` command has no options.

How can I do that?

Comment: maybe `attach`?

Comment: Attach local standard input, output, and error streams to a running container. 
This allows you to view its ongoing output or to control it interactively, as though the commands were running directly in your terminal.
$ docker attach [OPTIONS] CONTAINER ?

Comment: What's wrong with creating a new container?  IME you basically never need `docker start`.  Are you perhaps looking for [`docker-compose logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_logs/) which will give you the output of one of the running containers?